# Pipe Grep Results to Sed — Only do sed on results of grep

Tags: sed, grep

[Mac OS]

It seems that sed requires an input file, and that I cannot pipe grep to it. Although sed can match like grep does, it can make the sed operation very complex if it's handling both a find and replace.

For example, if I wanted to remove the 3rd word of every line that started with 'T', it's much more convenient to separate the find/replace commands than to create a complex regex.

Looking through SO answers, there doesn't seem to be an elegant solution where you can pipe grep to sed without new files being involved. I did find this, which almost does what I want:

```
sed -i "s/$(grep 'old' input.txt)/new/g" input.txt
```

But it doesn't handle multiple matches well.

I'll generalize:

Is there a better way to find specific lines in a text file and modify those lines in-place? Preferably cli, or as low-level as possible.

Comment: Sed was created to modify streams (**s**tream **ed**itor) and doesn't require an input file. Did you try to use `-i` with a stream? It's file specific and has no meaning when manipulating a stream. Also, `-i` on macOS sed requires an extra argument for the backup file created, `-i ''` for no backup file.

Comment: adding a small sample input file along with complete expected output will help to understand your problem better.. sed has filtering options built-in, so you may not need grep at all..... for example: `sed '/T/ s/old/new/' ip.txt`

Comment: @Sundeep - Didn't realize it had a filter option. That satisfies my needs, thanks!